# OLE date (number) to date (string)

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am debugging an application that I ported from Windows, to *nix, a little while ago. The app stores dates as doubles (using the OLE Date format). I need to be able to inspect the dates - as human readable strings. I cant find an online conversion tool, so I decided to roll my own.

I was originally going to write an OpenOffice function, but I think it would be more straightforward to use one of the .Net languages, to write a small console app that accepts the double as a parameter and prints the date string to the console.

I am relatively new to .Net (though I have dabbled with both C# and VB.Net in the past). Can anyone help with my main() function? - snippets in either VB.Net or C# will be equally useful.

Comment: ok, I just had a look at the MSDN docs. This looks kinda easy. all I need to know is how to convert a double (i.e. an OLE Date representation) into a DateTime. I cant find a ctor for DateTime that takes a double though - any help?

Comment: ok, it was trivial like I thought. Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `DateTime.FromOADate([double])`

Comment: Thanks. Slightly beat you to it! :)